# 234.x.x.x IP address - what is it

Tags: udp, ip-address, multicast

I've done a fair bit of UDP socket programming in the past, but have only ever heard of the usual reserved IPs:

- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.x.x
- 10.x.x.x

But from an IP2Location it says multicast. Is **234.5.5.1** an actual IP address or reserved?

Comment: It's not a programming related question.

Comment: The reason comes from here http://udppockettrace.codeplex.com/ but I've updated it to be a less specific IP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out:
[Wikipedia - IP Multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Multicast)

Specifically the addressing section.

Comment: So it could've just been 234.0.0.1 instead of 234.5.5.1

Comment: Yup, reserved IPs are usually given as entire ranges.

Comment: Also, 127.0.0.1 can just as well be 127.111.222.42.